# Arch Linux Apache2 500 server error htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working on a project in a group. I'm the only guy using Linux. Anyways, we use git and there's one file which causes me problems.

The htaccess contains the following:

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all granted
</IfModule>
```

If I comment out the `Require all granted`, it works, however, when it's not commented out, it gives me a 500 server error.

I do have `authz_core_module` and I can't disable it because if it's not a module it will `Deny from all`.

Why is that line giving me a 500 server error? The file works correctly at all those other guys who use Windows. Is it something because of my Linux apache?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding these 2 lines to my `httpd.conf` file:

```
<Directory /THEPATHHERE/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride FileInfo Indexes Authconfig
</Directory>
```